# BizTalk HTTPReceive request response with BTSHTTPReceive.dll?ReqResp

Tags: http, request, biztalk, response

I've started to try out BizUnit and noticed that the Http Request Response have a URL of BTSHTTPReceive.dll?ReqResp

I can't find anything in the doc's about using the *?ReqResp*

Is this needed?, or does it add some value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you're sending a GET or a POST request. In general terms (and particularly for POST requests), the querystring can be used to host multiple receive locations through a single BTSHTTPReceive.dll, providing a way to difference the URL for each request location through the added query string params.

For GET requests, it can also be used as a way to pass data into the request message to the adapter. See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms962150.aspx) for the details.